# How do I get my navigation items to center in my nav?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[image]

I can't figure out why my mobile navigation items (green boxes) are not centering.

I've tried commenting out all other bits of code and I still see the block. It looks like the core of the problem is that space is applied between the `ul` and the `individual_nav_items`, but I have no idea where it's coming from.

The body tag wrapping is the black box in the image.

```css
  @media screen and (max-width: 740px) {
  nav {
    display: block;
    background-color: red;
  }
  ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    border: solid;
    border-color: blue;
  }
  .individual_nav_item {
    border: solid;
    border-color: lawngreen;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
  }
```

```html
<nav>
  <button onclick="toggleNav()" id="mobileNav" class="hamburger hamburger--slider" type="button">
    <span class="hamburger-box" >
      <span class="hamburger-inner"> </span>
    </span>
  </button>

  <ul>
    <a href="/index.html" class="individual_nav_item">Home</a>
    <a href="/about_us.html" class="individual_nav_item">About Us</a>
    <a href="#" class="individual_nav_item">FAQ</a>
    <a href="#" class="individual_nav_item">Contact</a>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: What do you mean by centering? Horizontally centered or vertically centered?

Comment: @Terry Thanks, I'd like the green boxes to center vertically within the blue box.

Comment: The blue box is stretched to the height of the green box, so it is centered...?

Comment: @Terry I guess I got it wrong then, I want them to center horizontally :) I'd like the green boxes to take up the entire space horizontally if that helps explain.

Comment: Then use `flex-direction: row;` or simply not specify it (it defaults to row anyway)

Comment: @Terry thanks for offering the solution but I do want them to flex vertically so that they take up the entire vertical space. But I also want them to take up 100% of the width of the screen. Right now, in the image above, they are only taking up about 90% of the width of the screen and I have no idea why they aren't taking up the other 10% on the left.

Comment: That's because all `ul` elements have some kind of margin or padding by default. You will need to set them to 0. You can easily find this out by inspect the element in your browser dev tools. Also, since you do no have a specific height for the `<ul>` element, its height is autosized to its content height.

Comment: @Terry thanks for the advice on inspecting the browser dev tools, I hadn't thought of that but it identified that it was a static 40px applied to the padding on the ul. I searched everywhere in my code and never found where it was coming from so I just added a ```padding-left:0``` to the ul element and it fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: That's a browser default styling that you need to overwrite: also why CSS resets are useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the following CSS displaying what you are trying to achieve ?

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 740px) {


nav {
    display: block;
    background-color: red;
  }

  ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    align-items: center;
    border: solid;
    border-color: blue;
  }

  .individual_nav_item {
    border: solid;
    border-color: lawngreen;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    width: 100%;
  }
```

Comment: Yes, this does work, the issue was specifically a padding-left of 40, so zeroing out, as you suggested worked. Thanks!